# DirectoryStream with PathMatcher not returning any paths

Tags: java, file, wildcard

Although I've seen a lot of answers for similar questions I can't make the following code work as I think it should:

```
File dataDir = new File("C:\\User\\user_id");
PathMatcher pathMatcher = FileSystems.getDefault()
    .getPathMatcher("glob:" + "**\\somefile.xml");
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(
    dataDir.toPath(), pathMatcher::matches)) {
    Iterator<Path> itStream = dirStream.iterator();
    while(itStream.hasNext()) {
        Path resultPath = itStream.next();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {...
```

I expected to get a list of paths to all "somefile.xml" under C:\User\user_id and all subdirectories below that. Yet the hasNext() method returns false every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DirectoryStream` only iterates through the directory you give it and matches entries in that directory. It does **not** look in any sub-directories.

You need to use one of the walkXXXX methods of `Files` to look in all directories. For example:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(dataDir.toPath())) {
  stream.filter(pathMatcher::matches)
        .forEach(path -> System.out.println(path.toString()));
}
```

Note: The `Stream` returned by `Files.walk` (and several other methods in `Files`) **must** be closed or resources will be leaked. Using a try-with-resources statement as shown here is recommended.

Comment: Did it just a bit different (limited to Java 7 here) but that did solve my problem. Thanks!